# Why does $(A- \lambda I)^2 =0$ if A has two repeated eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation, jordan-normal-form

This statement appears in my textbook as part of an introduction of the method for finding the Jordan form of a $2 \times 2$ matrix. I understand what it says but I'd really like to know where is it coming from or what is the proof of it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix that has and eigenvalue $\lambda$ repeated twice, then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(x-\lambda)^2$, and so by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, which says that a matrix annihiliates its characteristic polynomial, you get $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ has two repeated eigenvalues $\lambda$, then its Jordan form is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & * \\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in other words, $A$ is conjugate to a matrix of the above form. Since conjugate matrices have the same characteristic polynomial, and the characteristic polynomial of the above matrix is $(x-\lambda)^2$. By Cayley-Hamilton, the claim follows.